# PHP from WAMP server not seeing .htaccess file when running from cmd

Tags: php, .htaccess, cmd, console, wamp

an htaccess file is read and applied when location entered in browser but not from php in cmd.

Everything is all right when I enter the URL from my browser in localhost `WAMP` server. 
But when I run the command from cmd it does act like there are not any `.htaccess` file.

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14 C:\MyProject\dev.project1\test.php
```

It throws lots of errors particularly this:

```
include_once(): failed to opening library/Configuration.php for inclusion <include_path='.;C:\php\pear'> in test.php
```

This doesn't happen from browser though. It includes everything properly. In the `.htaccess` file I have:

```
php_value include_path "C:\MyProject\dev.project1"
```

Running test.php from browser working perfectly. But not in cmd.

So how can I make PHP from cmd read the `.htaccess` a file like a browser version?

Edit: I also have other rules in `.htaccess`. Like `rewrites`, `setenv` for connecting to the database, etc. It is a must for me. In Linux, I am calling php from `cronjob` but this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: There is no web server involved when you run PHP from the command line. If you want the include path modified for the command line too either pass the path in the call or modify the PHP ini file to include the include path you want to use.

Comment: I also have other rules in .htaccess like setenv, filesmatch, rewrite conditions etc. Is there a way to call Apache from cmd? Also this wasn't giving any problems in Linux environment. Why is that?

Comment: It is normal to have different INI files for Apache and command line use. Can't possibly answer your question about Linux but chances are good that there were separate INI files involved. You can do the same thing on Windows of course. Like I said, move most of the things you need into an INI file and use that when calling your program from the command line. Or have one INI file and specify it on the call to PHP from the scheduler.

Comment: So are you saying that there is a way to involve web server when running PHP from command line?

Comment: No and why would you? If you need to run something through a web server perhaps `cURL` would help. One doesn't usually take something designed for a browser and start using it from the command line. Different audiences (usually) and very different environments. Maybe if you [edit]ed your question and expand more on exactly what you are trying to do other solutions might be feasible.

Comment: Yes you are right but what confused me is this: Normally this file is running through the console command in linux. In cronjob: Like /usr/local/zend/bin/php  /var/www/html/dev.project1/test.php